# Error "change this to a CNAME record" on Github pages custom domains despite having a CNAME set up

Tags: github, dns, github-pages

I'm setting up a custom domain on Github pages which I've set as `www.dineshraj.com` and I have a CNAME record on my registrar that reads as follows:

`CNAME   www.dineshraj.com   dineshraj.github.io`

This is the only DNS record I have set.

However when I go to the Pages options for my repo in Github, I get the following error:

> Your site's DNS settings are using a custom subdomain, www.dineshraj.com, that's set up as an A record. We recommend you change this to a CNAME record pointing at [YOUR USERNAME].github.io"

I think this also has the knock on effect of not me not being able to enable Enforced HTTPS.

I don't have any A records listed so I'm a bit confused.

Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: I'm having this same problem, did you end up fixing it? I'm trying to use Squarespace (formerly Google Domains) to have my site that's hosted on Github pages redirect to my custom domain. In the Squarespace DNS I've created 4 A records, 4 AAA records (for IPv6), and a CNAME record to point from the domain to github pages: https://i.imgur.com/jK43mZJ.png The Github pages configuration still isn't working, the DNS check is failing.

Answer (score 0):

In the control panel of your DNS provider, you should be able to see that an entry is already added to your DNS configuration for *[www.dineshraj.com](http://www.dineshraj.com)* and it's set up as an **A** record.
In my case, I have been advised to remove this entry and re-add an entry for  *[www.dineshraj.com](http://www.dineshraj.com)* but as a **CNAME** record.